# What is the code base line count border for introducing unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I wonder if there is such a thing as a code line count for a project after which it's preferable to start introducing unit tests, so the things don't get out of control. I think that for some small projects (5-10k lines of code for example) you won't need unit testing, but for large ones of course it's a good idea. Our project is about 100k lines of code, and we already have fears when it comes to making some changes.

So how do I know when to start introducing unit tests in the project ?

Comment: Since the question really asks for opinions, I expect this question will be voted closed. However, if you're using test-driven development, the line number count at which you would start to introduce unit tests would be 0 lines of functional code. Thus, the answer to the question could be "anytime from zero lines upwards".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, whether or not to unit test depends on your motivation for testing.

- Is the software mission-critical?
- What is the cost of a failure?
- How easily can you address errors, if they occur?

The higher the cost of failure, the more important it is to test your software. Here I'm reminded of [Steve Freeman's excellent article on **Safe Fail** versus **Fail-Safe**](http://www.higherorderlogic.com/2011/04/tdd-embracing-failure/). At one end of the spectrum, you can just let your software fail, and fix the errors as they pop up in the wild; at the other end of the spectrum, an error could be disastrous (loss of life).

Thus, it's impossible to answer the question as posed, but I second Simon's comment above that if you do Test-Driven Development (which comes with a lot of other benefits), the line count at which you start unit testing is 0.